# Expo: Compile TypeScript files from specific node_modules

Tags: typescript, react-native, webpack, expo, babeljs

I would like to make Expo/Babel(7) compile some modules inside `node_modules` using TypeScript, but I don't seem to find a way how to configure it.

What's strange is that it does transform TypeScript in the project root by default without any configuration, but not in `node_modules`.

Adding `ignore: []` into `babel.config.js` as suggested in [Babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register) does not work. I can see that Babel parses some of the react-native/expo files from `node_modules` though as setting `test` option to anything will break the build.